# Dell xps 9350 battery voltage issue

Tags: voltage

I have Dell XPS 9350 model which has battery issue. So I brought another new battery which is not original yet good one. Now my question is My original battery has 7.6v but the other battery which I brought has only 7.4v so will there be any problem in future ?

Comment: How do you get these voltages? Measure them?

Comment: It was written on the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that battery if the voltage specification doesn't match, or you can't contact Dell and confirm compatibility.

Using a battery which differs from the specification could potentially risk damage to the hardware or the user through some kind of failure in the battery or laptop.

it may only be .2 volts out but it's really not worth the risks. If you can't confirm with Dell, go back to the vendor of your new battery and ask them, they may be able to provide you with evidence of compatibility.